# No rule to make target for gTest

Tags: ros, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While using `$ catkin_make run_tests_test_pkg`, the following error is generated by cmake:

`*** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libgtest.so', needed by '/home/username/catkin_ws/devel/lib/test_pkg/sampleTest'.  Stop.`

I uninstalled gtest (and ROS) and reinstalled it again, but the error persists.
The tests are successfully built on another system (ensured via git) with same OS (ubuntu 14.04)

What are the possible reasons for this error, and how can this be removed?

**EDIT**: CMakeLists.txt (unchanged, except for minor filename modifications:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_library)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS my_msgs geometry_msgs roscpp roslib sensor_msgs std_msgs actionlib actionlib_msgs)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS my_msgs geometry_msgs roscpp roslib sensor_msgs std_msgs actionlib actionlib_msgs
)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")

include_directories(
  include/
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set(math_HDRS
    include/my_library/math/abc.h
    include/my_library/math/xyz.h
)

set(math_SRCS
    src/math/xyz.cpp
)

set(math_test_HDRS
    ${math_HDRS}
    include/my_library/math/abc_test.h
    include/my_library/math/xyz_test.h
)

set(math_test_SRCS
    ${math_SRCS}
    src/math/main_test.cpp
)

add_library(my_library ${actionlib_HDRS} ${actionlib_SRCS} ${math_HDRS} ${math_SRCS})  # ${param_HDRS}     ${param_SRCS})
add_dependencies(my_library ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(my_library ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} yaml-cpp)
set(CMAKE_C++_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(my_library PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

catkin_add_gtest(math_test ${math_test_SRCS} ${math_test_HDRS})
```

**EDIT**: clean cmake output (removed mangled c++ function names, and repetition of errors):

```
Base path: /home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make run_tests_my_library -j8 -l8" in "/home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target math_test
[100%] Building CXX object my_library/CMakeFiles/math_test.dir/src/math/main_test.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/my_library/math_test
CMakeFiles/math_test.dir/src/math/main_test.cpp.o:(txt+0x07): In file /home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/my_library/src/math/main_test.cpp
*** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libgtest.so', needed by '/home/kunaltyagi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/my_library/math_test'. Stop.
CMakeFiles/math_test.dir/src/math/main_test.cpp.o:(txt+0xc1): In function 'testing::internal::FormatForComparisonFailureMessage(char const*, std::string const&)':
/usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:1328: error: undefined reference to 'testing::internal::EqFailure(char const, char const, testing::internal::String const&, testing::internal::String const&, bool)'
**** repeat this multiple times for each usage of ASSERT_EQ and EXPECT_EQ****
/usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:1328: error: undefined reference to 'testing::internal::EqFailure(char const, char const, testing::internal::String const&, testing::internal::String const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [my_library/CMakeFiles/math_test.dir/src/math/main_test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [my_library/CMakeFiles/math_test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [my_library/CMakeFiles/run_tests_my_library.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [run_tests_my_library] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199180/no-rule-to-make-target-for-gtest/) by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-12-10**:
After reinstalling have you deleted the `build/CMakeCache.txt` file? If not, please do so and try another (clean) build. If it still doesn't work please post the complete output of CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The troubleshooting here is pretty simple: check that the file in question exists, and maybe check which package owns it on both systems (`dpkg -S /usr/lib/libgtest.so`).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-12-10**:
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/libgtest.so

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-12-10**:
gtest does not install a system wide library. It must be build for each project you want to use it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-10**:
@kunaltyagi: I think you missed the first step: check if the file in question exists; preferably on both systems. **YOU** need to determine how your systems differ.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-10**:
@dirk-thomas: in theory, yes. In reality, catkin usually hides that from the user.

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-12-10**:
@ahendrix: The output is same on both systems, the file does not exist on both the systems.
@dirk-thomas: I know. That's wht I am puzzled. gtest is built per package, by toplevel.cmake, the cmake for gtests is in /opt/ros//share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake for a default installation

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-10**:
@kunaltyagi: is it possible that you're missing the cmake call that triggers compilation of gtest, and it happens to work on one machine because you have a package somewhere else in your workspace that is triggering the compilation of gtest for you?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-12-10**:
@kunaltyagi Please post more information: the complete output of a clean build, the CMakeLists.txt of your package etc.